# Women behind the kohanim during birchas kohanim

Tags: women, birchas-kohanim

The halacha is during birchas kohanim you can not be behind the kohenim. Does anyone know if this does or does not apply to women in the ezras nashim in a situation where part of the ezras nashim is behind the kohanim?
I have never heard of anyone telling the women to move back, and can not find it discussed.
The only reason I can think of is maybe they are considered "anusim" for some reason. Which then they would be similar to the "am sha'bisados" that are included in the berachah even though they are not even in shul.(If they are required to move and they do not it would come out that it would have been better for them to stay home).
See shulchan orach, orach chain 128-24 and MB there

Comment: Why might it be different than the men's section?

Comment: @DoubleAA Because it's not uncommon and we prefer not to invalidate existing minhagim.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying (I frankly don't think I've ever see women's sections that are behind the duchan), but try saying it clearly in an [edit] to the post so everyone can understand why you are asking.

Comment: @DoubleAA To quote the Taz from the answer below, חלילה ללמד חובה על העומדים על מקומם

Comment: The MB in 90:21 brings from the knesses hagadolah that many Shuls have their azara on the eastern side forcing them to daven with their back to the aron. Although he doesn’t recommend it, there were obviously such cases. So the question is, what did they do for Birchas kohanim

Comment: There are many many shuls where the ezras nashim is the entire second floor (very common in Brooklyn where shuls are in longer lots), so there are definitely women who will be behind the kohanim.

Comment: @shlomoBMG Upstairs is not the same as behind the kohanim, but in any event even if such places exist, in the case of things women clearly do because they were largely uneducated until modern times, it's hard to see value in not just telling them the traditional halacha now that we also teach them obscure things like reading and writing.

Comment: @DoubleAA The mechaber there says even a "mechitza shell barzel" so i assume upstairs is not different.

Comment: Upstairs isn't different from the main floor of shul, it's just still not behind

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/885014/rabbi-mordechai-djavaheri/look-at-me-when-i-talk-to-you-facing-the-kohanim-when-they-bless-us/

Comment: @DoubleAA what he means to ask, I believe, is that if the upstairs runs the length of the shul, and there are seats in the front of the Ezras nashim that are behind the kohanim, but they are upstairs. Do they need to walk to the back so that they are in front of them, or since their upstairs anyway, there’s no difference. Nobody ever heard of anyone taking the ladies to move back. These type of situations are common in Brooklyn Shuls that are housed in two story homes

Comment: @Chatzkel For centuries nobody had ever heard of telling women to daven or bentch or follow numerous other halachot.

Comment: @Chatzkel everywhere I've been, the ladies did indeed move back, so I'm not sure about "nobody ever heard"

Answer (score 3):

As a practical answer, in every shul I've been in where the women's section extends past the duchan, the women move to in front of it for Bircas Kohanim. I was taught to do so in school, and practically speaking I've always seen it done, so I'm not sure the premise of this question is even true.

Answer (score 2):

The Taz on Orach Chaim 128:24, says that it was done like that in his days - even men - and says that the reason might be because the Aron Kodesh is considered an extension of the wall, being that they are attached - unlike the times of the Gemara - and therefore it is considered as if the Kohanim standing in front of it are standing right next to the wall

Also, the Shulchan Aruch (Ibid) says that someone who is unable to attend Shul still receives the blessing, and the Bach says that the same would apply in a case where there is no room to stand in front of the Kohanim

Comment: He doesn't say it's OK, but he's מלמד זכות on those who don't move.

Comment: The shulchan aruch doesn't apply because they already showed up to shul. And Bach won't help, because in the same way there's room for the men to move there's room for the women to move.

Answer (score 0):

Tosfos [Sotah 36B](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Sotah.38b.20.1?lang=bi) seems to indicate that they would have to move to the front if they can:

> י"ל דדוקא בדלא אניסי קמבעיא ליה אבל בדאניסי פשיטא דמי גרע מאחיהם שבשדות וא"ת אי לא אניסי אמאי עדיפי מעם שאחורי הכהנים בלא הפסק מחיצה י"ל עם שאחורי הכהנים מראין בעצמן כאילו אין הברכה חשובה בעיניהם דכתיב אמור להם פנים כנגד פנים והן עומדים אחורי עורף **אבל בהפסק מחיצה *כיון דלא קיימי אחורי עורף* לאו מילתא היא** דלא חזינן דקפיד קרא בהכי

Although I believe Tosfos can be read two ways, it seems that he’s saying that being behind a Mechitza without a ones, is ok since your not behind them. (Alternatively, he’s saying that no matter what, being behind a Mechitza is never counted as being behind the kohanim since it isn’t showing disrespect. However this doesn’t sound to be the simple reading)